# How to display Drupal Commerce user orders on drupal calendar page/block?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, calendar, google-calendar-api, drupal-commerce

Can Drupal calendar be used to display user orders on block or page on user dashboard so that they can see their all orders status on calendar. There is already a view that shows orders in tabular form, but can Drupal calendar can be used to show users orders as well?

Any suggestion / ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Every view has its template files. And you can edit them, meaning you can "force" them to display what every you want. So find template file ("Theming information" on view edit page / Advanced options can be helpful) you want to upgrade and add your code there which will get user order for that day and display them.

Answer (score 0):

It is now possible to display Commerce Orders in a Calendar View with this module: https://drupal.org/project/calendar_view